# How can I get data between previous week and current date?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have tried below script but it did not work...

```
EventLog_EffectiveDate between DATEADD(WW, 0, getdate()) and DATEADD(WW, -1, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

try to invert date

```
EventLog_EffectiveDate between DATEADD(WW, -1, getdate()) and  DATEADD(WW, 0, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
column BETWEEN first and last
```

is always equivalent to

```
column >= first AND column <= last
```

So you always have to ensure that your lower valued item is `first` and higher valued item is `last`:

```
EventLog_EffectiveDate between DATEADD(WW, -1, getdate()) and DATEADD(WW, 0, getdate())
```

That just leaves us with the puzzle of what you think `DATEADD(WW, 0, getdate())` is doing for you and whether these computed dates are actually the ones you wanted. If you could add a bit more explanation to your question (if these aren't correct) of what dates you do want to search between, I can try updating this answer further.